# How can I share Sibelius templates across devices?

Tags: sibelius

I'm using Sibelius Ultimate on Mac. In the latest version it is really easy to set up default templates by Exporting files as Manuscript Paper. It then stores these template files in a Manuscript Paper folder, and they are available to open in the Quick Start Menu.

However, I would like to be able to access these templates on more than one computer, so that I don't have to keep updating templates on each computer. How can I do this?

I tried putting an Alias to an iCloud file in the Manuscript Paper folder; Sibelius won't open using an alias from the Quick Start Menu.

I know I could just save a folder of template Sibelius files in iCloud to open when I need them, but I just wondered if there was a better way to do this, so that they are available in Quick Start.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify your main Scores folder to be in a cloud-shared location.   I don't think it's practical to do this with a User folder, like the one Sibelius stores Manuscript Papers in.

But those Manuscript Paper files are only normal Sibelius files, placed in that particular location so that Quick Start will recognise them.  So keep your main Scores folder in iCloud.  When you create or modify a Manuscript Paper, immediately create a new score using it, and immediately save it under a suitable name into the shared folder.  You can then use it as a template on any computer that accesses that iCloud account.  For the extra convenience of having in in Quick Start, immediately Export: Manuscript Paper on THAT computer.

Not a completely transparent process.   But a lot easier than modifing a Manuscript Paper score individually on each computer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to locate your Manuscript folder as follows. macOS: /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Avid/Sibelius. Find your specific manuscript papers, make copies and store them in the cloud, from where you will be able to access them from another device. Copy and paste them into your default folder on your second device, as above.

Comment: From the question: "I know I could just save a folder of template Sibelius files in iCloud to open when I need them, but I just wondered if there was a better way to do this, so that they are available in Quick Start."

Comment: If you copy and paste your new Manuscripts (from iCloud) onto your 2nd device in the same folder as the other Manuscript papers on your 1st device, they should show up in the QuickStart. @Aaron, I hope this helps?

Comment: I think the answer from @Laurence Payne is probably the easiest method.